# GAGA proof, analytification of endomorphism is the 0 map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Serre's GAGA he proves theorem 3: given M on $X^h$ there exists coherent algebraic sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on X s.t.  $\mathscr{F}^h$  is isomorphic to M , unique up to isomorphism.

He proves that it suffices to prove existence of $\mathscr{F}$ **on X** = $\mathbb{P}_r(\mathbb{C})$, where  $\mathscr{F}$ is defined on Y $\subset$ X = $\mathbb{P}_r(\mathbb{C})$ on X.

He states in the proof: given x $\in$ X, let f $\in$ $\mathscr{J}(Y)$, let $\phi$ be multiplication by f on $\mathscr{G}_x$. Thus somehow $\phi^h$ of  $\mathscr{G}_x^h$= $\mathscr{M}_x^h$ is the zero map, because  $\mathscr{M}$ is a coherent analytic sheaf on $Y^h$??.

where $phi^h$ is defined in definition 2, page 11 in the English translation version of GAGA.

Why is $\phi^h$ the zero map?! Please help.

Comment: $\mathcal{M}_x$ is a $\mathcal{H}_x$/$\theta(\mathcal{I}_x)$ module in the terminology of the english translation of serre. Thus the multiplication is zero by $\theta(f)$. Hence the multiplication is zero by $f$.

Comment: where $\mathscr{H}(X)_x/\theta(\mathscr{J}(Y)_x)= \mathscr{H}_x(Y)$?

Comment: yes. That seems correct.